# How to trigger event listeners through javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 buttons (1 submit and 1 reset). I want to trigger the following events: onmousedown,onmouseup,onmouseover and onmouseout. I tested my code but it is not working :/. Would you mind helping me to fix it? 
**HTML:**

```
<div class="buttonwrap">
    <div id="eventlisten1">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </div>
    <div class="eventlisten2">
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function mDown(obj) {
    obj.value = "Submitted!"
}

function mUp(obj) {
    obj.value = "Thank you!"
}

function mOver(obj) {
    obj.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}

function mOut(obj) {
    obj.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function eListeners() {
    var eventlisten1 = document.getElementByClassName('eventlisten1');
    var eventlisten2 = document.getElementByClassName('eventlisten2');
    eventlisten1.addEventListener('mousedown', mDown, false);
    eventlisten1.addEventListener('mouseup', mUp, false);
    eventlisten2.addEventListener('mouseover', mOver, false);
    eventlisten2.addEventListener('mouseout', mOut, false);
}

window.onload = eListeners();
```

**CSS** (for some styling):

```
.buttonwrap {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    width:200px;
    background:#ccc;
}
input[type=submit] {
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px 0px 0px -1px;
    width:90px;
    background-color:#00ff00;
    float:left;
    border-radius:5px;
}
input[type=reset] {
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px 0px 0px 15px;
    width:90px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
    border-radius:5px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/mf2xD/2/
I will rep those nice people who help me out :)
Thank you!

Comment: Do you really mean to use the word "trigger"?  To "trigger" an event is to cause the event to happen; your code just establishes some event handlers.

Comment: Yea and I want to make them work.

Comment: That still does not make complete sense. Do you want to establish code that happens when the events naturally happen as a result of user activity? Or do you want to set up the handlers *and* force the browser to generate the events?

Comment: "Do you want to establish code that happens when the events naturally happen as a result of user activity?" - This, yep. I want to make those events happen but through `addEventListener` instead of adding the events in html

Comment: OK, well that's not what "trigger" means.  So - the code you've got has errors. You should **always** have the developer console open. If there are errors, the code's not going to do anything. In this case, a big problem is that there's no function called "getElementByClassName", and your elements don't have classes anyway. You're looking for "getElementById".

Comment: Yea, I know there are erros, thats why I am asking for your help. About the Id - it was misspelled by me. I've changed it to class already.

Comment: If you change the element to use "class" instead of "id", that will help (but you have to change both!). However it's still wrong. Have you opened up the developer console yet?  There is no function called "getElementByClassName".  It's "getElementsByClassName", with an "s", and it does not return a single DOM node - it returns a NodeList object.  In this case, you're much better off using "id" instead of "class", and using "getElementById()".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, for one, you're using `getElementByClassName()` when the element doesn't even have a class:

```
var eventlisten1 = document.getElementByClassName('eventlisten1'); // This one has no class
var eventlisten2 = document.getElementByClassName('eventlisten2');
```

Second problem is mispelling. `getElement` should be plural if you're fetching based on class.

Try this:

```
var elTwo = document.getElementsByClassName('eventlisten2')[0];
```

The above should return the first matched element with class `eventlisten2`.

Third problem is that there is no `obj` parameter being passed to your callback. You need to reference `this` So your listeners should look like this:

```
function mDown() {
    this.value = "Submitted!";
}
```

However, `this.value` actually won't work, because `this` refers to the `div` element (it's what you attached your handler to).

Three ways around this:

1. Attach your handlers to your input elements instead of the divs.
2. Get the input elements once your handler is called.
3. Get the input elements before your set your handlers, and pass the elements as a
   parameter to your handlers.

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mf2xD/4/)</kbd>

Comment: Well the first listener was misspelled bad (I fixed it) but still it does not work.

Comment: Did you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/mf2xD/2/ ? I updated but still the functions cannot be loaded when the button is clicked.

Comment: The input value attribute does not change though?

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload = eListeners();
```

should be

```
window.onload = eListeners;
```

You need to make the "onload" handler be the function itself, not the result of calling the function.

Now, that said, your question talks about **triggering** the events. The code you've got just establishes the event handlers.